# When should I open a skylight vent?

Tags: heating, insulation

I have a one-floor (plus basement) house with a large skylight in the living room.  It has an openable vent.  When is it proper to open the vent?

Should I open it in midsummer with the AC on, on the theory that the high hot air will leave?  What about spring/fall when no AC or heat is on, but it's hot-ish (or cold-ish) out?

Answer (score 2):

Use it only when the temps are moderate to exit warmer air from room when the outside temps are lower than inside and can come in through windows etc., like in the evening.  Once the outside temps are higher than what you want in your house and you have AC on, keep them closed.

Comment: And don't forget to factor for humidity.  If the humidity is high outside, you're better off keeping them closed and letting the AC do a little work rather than turning up the AC to deal with the humidity.